# java regex split string with white space(except when both left and right was number or - )

Tags: java, regex, capture-group

I have this string **how to split 5-28 14:00 - 5-28 18:00 the60s(.corp)**. I want to split it with white space except when the white space have number or **-** around them.

**The result I want was:**

```
1. how 
2. to
3. split
4. 5-28 14:00 - 5-28 18:00
5. the60s(.corp)
```

Thanks.

**The following is my code:**

```
String str = "how do I split 5-28 14:00 - 5-28 18:00 the60s(.corp)";
    str = str.replaceAll("\\s+(?!(?=-|\\d+))", "@");
```

First I replace the right white space with @ , then split the string with @. But it doesn't work.

Comment: A good starting point would be to post the code you tried, explaining what doesn't work, why, what you expected and what happened instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lookarounds for this:

```
(?<![-\d])\s+|\s+(?![\d-])
```

#### [Code Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fG7qM8)

Comment: I am sorry to forget the **-** ,just as the title says.